# Problem on trigonometric substitution of an integral

Tags: integration, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Suppose we have to find the integral of the function $\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}$. To solve this, I set $\sqrt{x} = -\sin\theta$, where theta belongs to [0, -π/2) which implies that $x = \sin^2\theta$. The differential $dx$ can then be expressed as $dx = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta$.So

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}} \, dx$$

$$= \int \sqrt{\frac{sin² \theta}{1-sin² 
 \theta}} \, 2\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta$$
$$= \int \sqrt{\frac{sin² \theta}{cos² 
 \theta}} \, 2\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta$$
$$= \int 2sin² \theta d\theta $$

$$= \theta - \frac{\sin 2\theta}{2} + C $$
$$=-\arcsin(\sqrt{x}) - \sqrt{x(1 - x)} + C$$
But the correct answer is $$\arcsin(\sqrt{x}) - \sqrt{x(1 - x)} + C$$
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}} 
= \left\lvert \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}\right\rvert
= - \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}
$$

since $\sin\theta \leq 0$ and $\cos\theta > 0$.
So your last integrand has the wrong sign.

You made a second sign error, since $\sin(2\theta) = -\sqrt{x(1-x)}$
but you substituted $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$.
This partly canceled your first sign error, which is why the entire answer doesn't have its sign flipped, only the first term.

Why would you want to work in the fourth quadrant instead of the first?
It's much easier to keep track of signs when
$\lvert\sin\theta\rvert = \sin\theta$
rather than $-\sin\theta$.

Comment: I initially assumed that trigonometric substitution, which I typically apply in the first quadrant, could also be utilized in the fourth quadrant. However, I encountered an error during this process. Regardless, I appreciate your response, sir. Thank you

Comment: You certainly **can** do trig substitution in the fourth quadrant. It's just more work to do so. I usually try to introduce as few negative signs as I can, although if you can keep track of them it's sometimes fun to do something like this as a stunt.

Comment: So I gather you were just trying it to see if it worked. That's a good reason. You didn't quite get the answer, but you get my respect.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, sir.You also have my respect for spending your valuable time to help students like me

Answer (score 0):

Noting that $\dfrac{x}{1-x} \geqslant 0 \Leftrightarrow 0 \leqslant x<1$, as OP’s setting $\sqrt x=-\sin \theta$, then $\sin \theta\le 0$ and $\cos \theta \ge0.$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \sqrt{\frac{\sin ^2 \theta}{1-\sin ^2 \theta}} 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =2 \int\left|\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}\right| \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =-2 \int \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} \cdot \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =-\int(1-\cos 2 \theta) d \theta \\
& =-\theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}+C \\
& =-\theta+\sin \theta \cos \theta \\
& =\sin ^{-1} \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x} \sqrt{1-x}+C 
\end{aligned}
$$
On the other hand, if OP sets $
\sqrt{x}=\sin \theta\text { for } \theta \in\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)
,$ then $$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \sqrt{\frac{\sin ^2 \theta}{1-\sin ^2 \theta}} 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =2 \int\left|\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}\right| \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =2 \int \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} \cdot \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =\int(1-\cos 2 \theta) d \theta \\
& =\theta-\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}+C \\
& =\theta-\sin \theta \cos \theta+C \\
& =\sin ^{-1} \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x} \sqrt{1-x}+C 
\end{aligned}
$$